# ¿Como reemplazar la vista en odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo

En el modelo de stock.picking de odoo estoy tratando de reemplazar la vista existente por una personalizada pero a la hora de hacer todo ese proceso me muestra ambas vistas y no una según esto solo hay que pasarle como referencia el id al que esta mostrando la vista pero me sigue mostrando ambas vistas en vez de solo mostrar la vista personaliozada

Adjunto codigo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<odoo>
<record id="view_recepciones_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">stock.piking.form</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <sheet>
                <div class="oe_title">
                    <group>
                        <field name="company_id"/>
                        <field name="partner_id" domain="[('company_id', 'in', [company_id, False])]"/>
                        <field name="picking_type_id"/>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="sheduled_date"/>
                        <field name="origin"/>
                    </group>
                </div>
                <separator string="Recepcion detallada"/>
                <notebook>
                    <page string="Entrada">
                        <group>
                            <tree editable="bottom">
                                <control>
                                    <create name="add_product_contrtol" string="Agregar prodctos de entrada"/>
                                </control>
                                <field name="default_code"/>
                                <field name="quantity_done"/>
                                <field name="product_uom"/>
                            </tree>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

este es el codigo de la vista personalizada que hice pero a la hora de actualizar el modulo muestra esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que debo hacer en este caso para solo mostrar la vista que hice y no que muestre ambas vistas

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que al heredar vistas tienes que especificar donde vas a colocar las customizaciones, en particular a mi me gusta trabajar con xpath. Entonces tendrias que reemplazar todo el form de la anterior vista

quedaria asi

```
<record id="view_recepciones_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">stock.piking.form</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//form" position="replace">
            <form>
                <sheet>
                    <div class="oe_title">
                        <group>
                            <field name="company_id"/>
                            <field name="partner_id" domain="[('company_id', 'in', [company_id, False])]"/>
                            <field name="picking_type_id"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="sheduled_date"/>
                            <field name="origin"/>
                        </group>
                    </div>
                    <separator string="Recepcion detallada"/>
                    <notebook>
                        <page string="Entrada">
                            <group>
                                <tree editable="bottom">
                                    <control>
                                        <create name="add_product_contrtol" string="Agregar prodctos de entrada"/>
                                    </control>
                                    <field name="default_code"/>
                                    <field name="quantity_done"/>
                                    <field name="product_uom"/>
                                </tree>
                            </group>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

el `<xpath expr="//form" position="replace">` es lo que hace toda la magia acá. solo recuerda estar seguro que no hay otro modulo que esté heredando esa vista porque sino va a dar error al tratar de buscar los elementos que ya no estarán en la customización